# Delete documents from Elasticsearch by DeleteByQueryAction

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete documents from ElasticSearch which have a specific id.

```js
// Create the low-level client
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder( new HttpHost(hostName, portName)).build();
    
// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

// And create the API client
ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    
public long delete( String indexName, String key, String value )
{   
    BulkByScrollResponse response =
    DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder( client )
            .filter( QueryBuilders.matchQuery( key, value ) ) 
            .source( indexName )
            .refresh( true )
            .get();                                             
    logger.info( "Deleted " + response.getDeleted() + " element(s)!" );
        
    return response.getDeleted();
}
```

I changed my pom.xml to

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>7.17.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol

> [ERROR]   symbol:   class ElasticsearchTransport

Comment: Are you making sure that you are using Elasticsearch version 7.17.9?

Comment: what is the elasticsearch version ?

Answer (score 0):

ElasticsearchTransport is a class of Elasticsearch Java API Client

try add dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
  <version>7.17.9</version>
</dependency>
```